# PHP warning: Illegal string offset 'field'

Tags: php

I am not understand why this code gives warning for php 5.4? How can i solve this problem?

```
 function load()
        {
                for ($i = 0, $n = sizeof($messages); $i < $n; $i++)
                {
                    $this->add($messages[$i]['field'], $messages[$i]['type']);
                }
        }

    function add($field, $type)
        {

            $this->messages[] = array('field' => $field, 'type' => $type);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = 0, $n = sizeof($messages); $i < $n; $i++) { ... }

$this->add($messages[$i]['field'], $messages[$i]['type']);
```

`$messages` does not exists in current scope. Instead, you should use `$this->messages` (that's probably declared as property).

Comment: This warning message is new to PHP 5.4. Old versions didn't warn if this happened.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that if your array were to have correct indexation it would start with 0 as the first element most likely. Whereas sizeof gives the amount off elements.
E.G. Element 10 in the array will have index [9]. To work around this you could do minus 1 for the limit like this:

```
for ($i = 0, $n = sizeof($messages) - 1; $i < $n; $i++){ ... }
```

That said, Unixarmy's solution is better but this is definitly something to keep in mind. Else you'll get atleast 1 error for the last element every single time

Comment: This warning message is new to PHP 5.4. Old versions didn't warn if this happened.