# PHP 5.4 warning: Illegal string offset 'field'

Tags: php

I am not understand why this code gives warning for php 5.4? How can i solve this problem?

```
function load(){
    for ($i = 0, $n = sizeof($messages); $i < $n; $i++){
        $this->add($messages[$i]['field'], $messages[$i]['type']);                       
    }
}

function add($field, $type){    
    $this->messages[] = array('field' => $field, 'type' => $type);
}
```

Comment: The array structure might be something else. Post `$messages`

Comment: You have asked same question twice duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32325667/php-warning-illegal-string-offset-field

Comment: as @b0s3 already mentioned, do a `var_dump($messages)` and edit your question to include the result, also your `load()` function does not take an array as parameter, where does the `$messages` array come from?

Comment: In the array **$messages** index **field** will not be set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function load(){
            for ($i = 0, $n = sizeof($messages); $i < $n; $i++){
                if(isset($messages[$i]['field']) && isset($messages[$i] ['field'])){
                $this->add($messages[$i]['field'], $messages[$i]['type']);
                }
               }                       
           }

function add($field, $type){    
        $this->messages[] = array('field' => $field, 'type' => $type);
        }
```